# PhpExcel Save file to a folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to save the  generated file to a folder located in the  server, I tried the  following code :

```
//save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
//if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
//force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
        $objWriter->save('‪C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\files\trials.xls');
```

but I keep getting the following error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fopen(â€ªC:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\files\trials.xls): failed
>   to open stream: Invalid argument
>
> Filename: PPS/Root.php
>
> Line Number: 90
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with
>   message 'Can't open â€ªC:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\files\trials.xls. It
>   may be in use or protected.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php:93
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(226):
>   PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('???C:\xampp\htd...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\controllers\time_sheet.php(6130):
>   PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('???C:\xampp\htd...') #2 [internal
>   function]: Time_sheet->save_time_sheet() #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\index.php(202):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php
>   on line 93

What is the best way to save the document?

Comment: So have you checked file/directory permissions?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes I have, the permision is full control for all users, I have tried the  same pointing to the  following folder C:\Users\user\Music\Playlists\trials.xls but still getting the same error

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear in what it's saying; The line of PHP code `fopen($filename, "wb")` has returned a failed result (boolean false), meaning that the specified filename can't be opened/created for writing. Unfortunately, PHP doesn't give any indication why this should be the case, but the most common reasons are file permissions, an invalid filepath or the file is already open with a lock against it