# PHPExcel Save a xls file to a specific folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to save a xls file to a specific folder on the  server using Php Excel using the following code :

```
  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
//force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD

        $objWriter->save('‪C:/xampp/htdocs/timesheet/files/test.xls');
```

But I keep on getting the following error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(â€ªC:/xampp/htdocs/timesheet/files/test.xls): failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Filename: PPS/Root.php

Line Number: 90


    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Can't open â€ªC:/xampp/htdocs/timesheet/files/test.xls. It may be in use or protected.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php:93 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(226): PHPExcel_Shared_OLE_PPS_Root->save('???C:/xampp/htd...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\controllers\time_sheet.php(6131): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('???C:/xampp/htd...') #2 [internal function]: Time_sheet->save_time_sheet() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\index.php(202): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\timesheet\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Shared\OLE\PPS\Root.php on line 93
```

Please advise on the  best way to save the  file on the  server.

Comment: Does the folder `C:/xampp/htdocs/timesheet/files` exist on your server, and have appropriate write permissions for your webserver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhpExcel Save file to a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559894/phpexcel-save-file-to-a-folder)

Answer (score 10):

Try changing the **`$objWriter->save()`** code to the following:

```
$objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,'folder_path/filename.xlsx',__FILE__));
```

You may change the filename and the file type depending on what you need.

Comment: nice will try this be back at you .