# Yii 2 Saving file to a particular folder while Using PHPexcel

Tags: php, file, yii2, phpexcel, yii2-basic-app

I tried to save the file into a specific folder using the following code from  a stack overflow thread [PHPExcel Save a xls file to a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603237/phpexcel-save-a-xls-file-to-a-specific-folder)

```
$objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,'folder_path/filename.xlsx',__FILE__));
```

Since I am using yii 2 I tried this method

```
 $objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,Yii::getAlias('@web')   .'/files/MyContacts.xlsx',__FILE__));
```

But it is not working the file still creates in the web (root folder). Is there a solution for the same ?

The error message i get is "Could not close zip file"  (i am using a Windows Operating System)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Yii::getAlias('@web')` returns URL of web application but for saving a file you need path of web application so try `\Yii::getAlias('@webroot')` instead.